# Ugly Number in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am a beginner in learning Ruby Language.
I am studying it from leetcode.

here have a solution, but I don't know why?
I would like to know what is structure in the solution

Ugly Number
solution:

```
def is_ugly(num)
   (2..5).each { |i| num /= i while (num % i == 0) } if num > 0 
   num == 1
end
```

1. I don't know why 'if' have to behind '}'

   It will be error if I delete 'if'statement

   > syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

and

2. `while (num % i == 0)`
   I can't understand this statement

   From what I Know while seems like :

eg.

```
while conditional [do]
     code
end
```

thanks a lot

Comment: *"here have a solution, but I don't know why?"* --- I can't really explain why this "solution" works, without knowing the question! What is an "ugly" number defined as?

Comment: Is [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/ugly-number/description/) the question? "Ugly numbers are positive numbers whose prime factors only include 2, 3, 5".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `if` and `while` are so-called postfix (short) forms.

Try these:

```
puts "yes" if true
```

and

```
puts "yes" if false
```

It is basically the same as:

```
if true
  puts "yes"
end
```

---

for `while`:

```
num /= i while (num % i == 0)
```

is exactly the same as

```
while (num % i == 0)
  num = num / i
end
```